# Cross-compatibility video formats in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera, Nginx server

Tags: html, video, nginx, flask

I'm using video.js plugin to play Mp4 and flv in browers in the html5 video tag. My study found that the formatting of the video matters and my video formats are not the issue now. Although flv and mp4's play in IE, safari, firefox, chrome in the development server (Flask) locally, the remote server in nginx shows problem playing flv in safari and mp4 in IE. Any suggestions?

Comment: What error does nginx return?